# Automatic callback to close fstream contained in file logger class

Tags: c++, class, callback, signals, fstream

To log different values in different parts of my c++ application I want to be able to instantiate a class that abstracts all the required commands for logging different values in a file. This is a prototype header of the class:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

....

class FileLogger {
 public:
  FileLogger(const std::string& log_name, const std::string& columnNames, const uint& columnCount, const double& timerOffsetSeconds = 0);

  // Checks if logging of previous timestamp is completed and 
  //starts a new row with logging the current time. 
  void startNewTimestamp();

  // different predefined methods to log several data types
  void logScalar(const double& value);
  void logVector(const Eigen::VectorXd& values);

  template <int SIZE, typename TYPE>
  void logArray(TYPE (&values)[SIZE]) {
    for (int i; i < SIZE; i++) {
      fileHandle_ << values[i] << ",";
      currentColumnCount_ += 1;
    }
  }

  // Method to close the fileHandle_ of the class
  void closeFileHandle();

 private:
  void checkLastTimestampCompletion();
  uint countColumnNames();

  std::string file_name_;
  uint currentColumnCount_;
  const uint columnCount_;
  const std::string columnNames_;

  std::ofstream fileHandle_;

  ....
};
```

The problem that i now experience, is that each class needs to close it's `fileHandle_` using the method `closeFileHandle()` before the program is terminated in order to obtain a working log. Since the program is usually terminated using `CTL +C` this needs to happen in a signal callback. I have found out that a termination signal can be used to execute a callback function as follows:

```
...
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>

void signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
  std::cout << "Caught signal " << signum << ", starting exit procedure." << std::endl;
  .... do something ...
  exit(1);
}

int main(){
  .... 
  signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
  ....
}
```

The only way I could find to close all the required `fileHandle_` of each instance of FileLogger class was to define them globally and to manually add `fileLogger.closeFileHandle();` to the callback function. This is undesirable for multiple reasons.

Therefore, I wondered if there is a way to somehow contain that functionality of closing the file handle upon exiting the program in the class itself in a way that the class can just be instantiated anywhere in the code? Or if that is not possible how could I handle the problem in another way?

Comment: Wouldn't the destruction of each `FileLogger` solve this automatically? `fileHandle_` will be closed when the `FileLogger` goes out of scope / when you call `std::exit`.

Comment: Unlreated: `std::cout << "Caught signal " << signum << ", starting exit procedure." << std::endl;` in a signal handler isn't portable. The standard allows very few things in signal handlers.

Comment: Thank you, you are right about the automatic close of the file handle. i guess i was led down a bad example where somebody closed them manually.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, I've seen a lot of those examples. Streams are rarely closed manually in C++ since the scope fixes it. I even prefer to add a scope rather than closing if I'm writing a function that does more than one `open` to the same file.

Comment: That information is very valuable indeed. my code runs fine now even without it. @TedLyngmo do you want to add a short answer so I can accept it and close the question? I hope the question can be useful to somebody else in the future this way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destruction of each `FileLogger` solves this automatically since `fileHandle_` will be closed when the `FileLogger` either goes out of scope or when you call `std::exit`.